# Cropping an image in android to fit width and cut off height

Tags: android, xml, crop

I have an ImageView which needs to have a maximum height of 150dp and a width that matches the parent. However, what I need is for the actual image to be cropped, so the picture is as wide as the ImageView, but centered and cropped so the top and bottom of the picture aren't visible (sort of a preview). What I have currently:

```
<ImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    android:background="#fafafa"

    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/articlepreviewimage"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/naslovclanka"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Also, it's crucial that the image stays in its' original proportions, so no putting it as background, no scaling etc. I just need it to fill up the width of the ImageView and show the center of the picture in that ImageView.

The way its' currently done, it scales the image so it fits into the height or width, but doesn't cut away anything. How to do this?

Comment: Ohh WOW!!! @Orlando Bloom is on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`
There are also a lot of other scale types that might fit what you what.

Comment: He is right, one thing - you need to set exact height of imageview. Another way to do this without scaling is to extend ImageView class and override onMeasure method

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/yourimageId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"/>
```